# spss convert syntax or csv to sav command prompt

Tags: export, spss

I need to use SPSS command prompt to convert syntax export to sav (I need to do it programatically from a wcf service). I tried using command prompt giving it sps, dat and spj file where spj is an xml with syntaxpath to sps and it does something but with no result (no file).

I opened the syntax file in spss and even in SPSS I only get option to save it as a syntax, not as a sav file.

What am I missing to create a sav file from these 3 files (dat or csv i guess, sps and spj)?

Answer (score 0):

A syntax file and a sav file are fundamentally different things.  You cannot convert one into other.  Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a SPSS newbie, dont know much of it. So basically I get a syntax export from somewhere which contains a .dat file (almost like csv, values separated by tab) and .sps which is something like metadata description for that .dat. I create .spj file that points to .sps and supposedly forward it to stats.exe (from the instructions i got "stats -production silent <filename.spj>" should produce .sav file but it doesnt work.